# Downcast in Boost.Python

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

EDIT: Corrected "upcast" to be "downcast".

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do downcasting in Python when the classes I'm working with come from C++. If I have two classes defined in C++ as:

```
struct Base
{
    int foo()
    {
        return 7;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    int bar()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};
```

And another function

```
Base baz()
{
    return Derived();
}
```

If I try in Python

```
der = baz()
print der.foo()
print der.bar()
```

The call to bar() fails because Python only knows about the functions in Base.

My solution was to add another function to Derived:

```
Derived * fromBase(Base * b)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Derived *>(b);
}
```

If I then change the first line of the Python script to read `der = Derived.fromBase(baz())`, the script works as expected.

However, the fact that I'm using a reinterpret_cast to make this work seems very wrong. Is there a better way to downcast that doesn't require using something as dangerous as reinterpret_cast? If there isn't, what should the return policy for `fromBase()` be?

Before anyone asks, yes, the downcast is necessary. This is how the library I must use works.

EDIT:

I'm looking for something that works like this C# code:

```
Base b = new Derived();
Derived d = b as Derived;
if (d != null)
    ...
```

Comment: dynamic_cast intead of reinterpret_cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Base baz()
{
    return Derived();
}
```

As can be seen from the return type, this returns a `Base` object, *not* a `Derived` object. So there's nothing to downcast (and not upcast) to. So you first need to fix that.

More to the point, you're right, `reinterpret_cast` definitively is shady in this context. `dynamic_cast` is in fact the tool to use for downcasts.

More fundamentally, you should ask yourself why you feel the need for a downcast. It may be the case that your example code is synthetic and not representative of your exact problem, but why shouldn't `baz` return a `Derived`?

---

Here is an equivalent of your snippet:

```
Derived d;
Base& b = d;
if(Base* p = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&b))
    // okay; b is actually an instance of Derived
```

Comment: No, what I said is correct. My example is not perfectly representative of the situation, but that shouldn't matter. In actuality Base is an interface class (it only has virtual functions) and that is what baz() returns. I have a feeling these classes that I must use were originally written in C# since upcasting there is much safer than in C++.

Comment: @Mr.Ambiguous What do you make of [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/a631e9769405270f9b6cb95ba3695e79)?

Comment: I don't care what that typeid function thinks the type is. I know that the memory pointed to contains a derived even if typeid sees it as a base. The fact that reinterpret_cast works is proof that this is the case. I'm just trying to find out if there is a safer way.

Comment: @Mr.Ambiguous `typeid` is not a function and reflects the actual dynamic type of an object of polymorphic type. If your code actually involves a `Derived` object, then your post should reflect that. As things are, `baz()` is *not* a `Derived` object. There is no need for a 'proof', those are the rules of the language.

Comment: My apologies. You are correct about the fact that I am trying to downcast. I assumed that a base would be at the bottom of a hierarchy and not (illogically) at the top. I think my understanding of how C++ works is totally off because when I added a virtual function to `Base` to make it compile with a `dynamic_cast`, the cast gave me back null. I changed it back to `reinterpret_cast` while leaving the virtual function and that caused the call to `bar()` to stop working.